# Is there a way to see the OAuth Messages Paw Sends?

Tags: oauth-2.0, paw-app

I am making the following request in my code and mirroring it in Paw:

https://paw.pt/daoS3vF5

Paw does all the heavy lifting in OAuth 2 (which is awesome) but in my code the library I am using is not dealing with the authentication renewal requests correctly.

When I run the request in Paw I can see it renewing the auth token.

Is there a way to see the renewal message(s) going back and forth so I know what to expect in a successful transaction?